# Eager Loader Relation в Yii2 REST

Tags: yii2

Модель вытягивается без связей и они подгружаются динамически для каждой модели, что неблагоприятно сказывается на производительности.

Получаю значения так

> /rest/url-checker/1?expand=patterns

Ответ имеет такой формат

```
<response>
    <title>Test</title>
    <is_active>0</is_active>
    <patterns>
        <item>
            <url_checker_pattern_id>1</url_checker_pattern_id>
            <url_checker_id>1</url_checker_id>
            <pattern>test</pattern>
            <added_on>2016-10-18 16:31:24</added_on>
        </item>
        <item>
            <url_checker_pattern_id>4</url_checker_pattern_id>
            <url_checker_id>1</url_checker_id>
            <pattern>test2</pattern>
            <added_on>2016-10-18 16:31:35</added_on>
        </item>
    </patterns>
</response>
```

Также не ясно как вытягивать только определённые поля а не все для relation. Так как мне нужно только значение pattern

```
<patterns>
    <item>
        <pattern>test</pattern>
    </item>
    <item>
        <pattern>test2</pattern>
    </item>
</patterns>
```

Контроллер

```
class UrlCheckerController extends ActiveController {

    public $modelClass = 'backend\modules\rest\models\UrlChecker';
}
```

Модель

```
class UrlChecker extends ActiveRecord {

    private $_patterns;

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getPatterns() {
        return $this->hasMany(UrlCheckerPattern::className(), ['url_checker_id' => 'url_checker_id']);
    }

    public function setPatterns($values) {
        $this->_patterns = $values;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes) {
        if (!$insert) {
            UrlCheckerPattern::deleteAll([
                'url_checker_id' => $this->url_checker_id,
            ]);
        }

        foreach ($this->_patterns as $pattern) {
            $relation = new UrlCheckerPattern();
            $relation->url_checker_id = $this->url_checker_id;
            $relation->pattern = $pattern;

            if (!$relation->save()) {
                throw new Exception('Relation don\'t save');
            }
        }

        parent::afterSave($insert, $changedAttributes);
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function fields() {
        return [
            'title',
            'is_active',
            'test' => function ($model) {
               /**
                * @var UrlChecker $model 
                * Тут пусто
                */
               return $model->relatedRecords;
            },
            /*'patterns' => function ($model) {
                $output = [];

                foreach ($model->patterns as $pattern) {
                    $output[] = [
                        'pattern' => $pattern->pattern,
                    ];
                }

                return $output;
            },*/
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function extraFields() {
        return [
            'patterns',
        ];
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Советую прочитать документацию yii2 по веб-сервисам REST: https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide-ru/README.md

Для отображения конкретной модели с предзагруженными данными без дополнительных запросов, вам нужно в контроллере переопределить метод 
`actionView($id)`:

```
public function actionView($id)
{
    // с помощью with() будет "жадная" загрузка данных, т.е. модель подгрузится сразу с указанными связями
    return UrlChecker::find()->where(['id' => $id])->with('patterns')->one();
}
```

Код не проверял, но должно работать. Выборка только одного поля "pattern" сильно вашу производительность не увеличит, но если так сильно этого хочется, то нужно снвоа работать с ActiveQuery и делать join вручную.

ps: изменил запись, в первой была ошибка по невнимательности. Если новый вариант не поможет, то отпишитесь